# How to set global API baseUrl used in useFetch in Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

How do I set the baseUrl that is used in the useFetch composable globally (maybe nuxt.config.ts)?

How can I avoid defining it in every useFetch?

Comment: You could probably put it into a composable and import it from there with your wished defaults.

Answer (score 40):

You can define the `baseURL` in your `nuxt.config.js|ts` like this:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'https://api.example.com/',
    },
  },
  // ...
```

(or use a fixed value or only the environment variable - as you like)

And add this composable:

```js
// /composables/useMyFetch.js

export const useMyFetch = (request, opts) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  return useFetch(request, { baseURL: config.public.baseURL, ...opts })
}
```

If you want type safety, you can achieve it like this:

```js
// /composables/useMyFetch.ts

export const useMyFetch: typeof useFetch = (request, opts?) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  return useFetch(request, { baseURL: config.public.baseURL, ...opts })
}
```

You can then use `useMyFetch` as replacement for `useFetch` - but with baseURL being set :-)

Comment: Should `return useFetch(() => request, { baseURL: config.public.baseURL, ...opts })` be `return useFetch(request, { baseURL: config.public.baseURL, ...opts })`?

Comment: thank you. This is really working very well

Comment: use answer from *Matt Sanders*. This one can't work well with TS & response type

Comment: You can use `config.public.baseURL as string` to fix the Typescript type error.

Answer (score 12):

The following composable could be set
`/composables/useJsonP.ts`

```js
export const useJsonP = async (path) => {
  return await useFetch(() => `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${path}`)
}
```

And you could call this in your view

```html
<script setup>
const jsonP = await useJsonP('todos/1')
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ jsonP.data }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

That way, no need to define it somewhere and hack somehow the configuration. You do have a simple way of defining reusable pieces of code, that are directly imported into your components/views thanks to the DX of Nuxt.

Comment: If I'm using a dynamic route like `await useJsonP('todos/' + route.params.id)` - I'm getting the data from the first fetching. Do you know why? I expected the return value will matching to the `params.id`. Example: path = `'todos/9'`, next path is `'todos/42'` - and the results are showing the results from todos with the id 9.

Comment: @wittgenstein `useFetch` is basically Nuxt2's `fetch()` lifecycle hook. If you want to retrigger it, you can call `refresh` as documented here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch#usefetch

Comment: There's never a reason to use `return await`, I think your `useJsonP` function may work also without `async/await`

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina the `return` may be skipped for performance reasons yes but a fetch is still an async operation, so totally need the `await`. Would you like to block people's UI while their slow network downloads the file?

Comment: no, `return await` is an antipattern. The function will stay async since `useFetch` returns a promise. Don't forget that `async/await` is syntactical sugar, removing `async/await` won't make the calls synchronous

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina this is what I said, no point into `return` here could be skipped. As for the rest, even if it may work I always `await` an HTTP call because it just sounds legit? Any kind of external request, writing operation or whatever is always awaited on my side, even if it takes just 10ms because it's a sane convention to have IMO haha.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking to do this in Typescript, you can infer the parameters from `useFetch` so you don't have to update your code if things change inside Nuxt.

**Make your base URL configurable from your environment**

As other folks have mentioned, first set your base URL in the public part of your [runtime config](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/configuration#environment-variables-and-private-tokens):

```
// nuxt.config.ts

import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'https://api.example.com/',
    },
  },
  // ...
```

**Wrap useFetch with your own composable**

The definition of `useFetch` uses a number of type variables, is overloaded and what is valid for the options argument actually changes depending on the request/results types that are passed to it. This makes it very difficult to re-type correctly.

To make matters worse, even if we do re-type it correctly, if the definition changes our wrapper won't be correct anymore. Luckily there is a pretty simple solution. Borrow the type of `useFetch` and re-use it:

```
// composables/useAPIFetch.ts

import { useFetch } from "#app"

type useFetchType = typeof useFetch

// wrap useFetch with configuration needed to talk to our API
export const useAPIFetch: useFetchType = (path, options = {}) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  // modify options as needed
  options.baseURL = config.public.baseUrl
  return useFetch(path, options)
}
```

Note we explicitly need to *not* re-declare any type variables, parameter argument types or return types, since we are borrowing all of them from `useFetch`'s type.

**Use your new composable**

Use it in your page / component and your types will flow through properly:

```
// components/Foo.vue

const { data, error, pending } = await useAPIFetch<ResultsType>("/my-path", { 
  method: "POST",
  body: data,
  ...
})
```

Comment: It only worked for me after I used another name instead of `baseURL` inside public in nuxt.config.ts. What could be the issue? when I used the name `baseURL`, the base url was automatically being set to `http://localhost:3000` which is where my nuxt server runs and API was on port 5000. It got fixed after I used another name.

Comment: @saadAhmed Is BASE_URL set in your environment variables or is it being populated in Nuxt?

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't set BASE_URL in my environment variables and assume it would fallback to  '//localhost:8000/api/', but no.

 runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || '//localhost:8000/api/',
    },
 },

Answer (score 5):

You can also involve **.env** like this

in **.env**

```
NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = https://www.someapi.com
```

in **nuxt.config.js/ts**

```
runtimeConfig: {
 
    public: {
      BASE_URL: 'some fallback value',
    },
  },
```

as it said in the document `BASE_URL` will be replaced by `NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL` automatically

( no need to use `process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL` )

and in composable you can use

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

console.log('base url is' , config.baseUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your nuxt.config file add this code

```
   runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
        baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'https://yourBaseURL.com/',
    },
}
```

then create a file in composables directory and use below code

```
 export const useCustomFetch = (request , opts)=>{
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    return useFetch(request,{baseURL:config.public.baseURL,
        onRequest({ request, options }) {
            // Set the request headers
        },
        onRequestError({ request, options, error }) {
            // Handle the request errors
        },
        onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
            // Process the response data
            return response._data
        },
        onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
            // Handle the response errors
        },
        ...opts})
}
```

now you can use this composable wrapper  in your components
in this composable you have interceptor to

Answer (score 1):

Can create a $fetch instance then reuse by creating a new composable. Below is an example for creating $fetch instance:

```
// Create a fetch object with a baseURL already setup
const apiFetch = $fetch.create({ baseURL: '/api' })

// Use it as if it was $fetch
const {data, pending, errors, refresh} = await apiFetch('/test') // Same as $fetch('/test', { baseURL: '/api' })
```

See: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/15930

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still looking for the answer to the original question you can do this in `nuxt.config` with runtimeConfig and env variables. You can of course replace the env variables with a hard-coded values if you prefer.

In your `nuxt.config.js/ts`

```
runtimeConfig: {
    SOME_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SOME_SECRET_KEY,
    public: {
      SOME_API_KEY: process.env.SOME_API_KEY,
    },
  },
```

Then in `someComposable.js`:

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
```

You can then access your variables as eg `config.public.SOME_API_KEY`

Hope that helps. More info here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/runtime-config