# How to access Nuxt 3 runtimeConfig in service file?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have service file like this .

**service/http.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios'
const config = useRuntimeConfig()

const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: config.public.apiUrl,
})
export default http
```

and **nuxt.config.js** like this

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiUrl: 'some value',
    }
  },
});
```

and **.env** like this

```
NUXT_API_URL=http://www.a.com/
```

and I want to access **apiUrl** here .

But it gives me an **error**.

[image]

also if I use **process.env.NUXT_API_URL** .

it gives an error again

so, how can I access **env** variable for my services file?

Comment: I'd recommend to use composables. And give `fetch` a try over `axios`.

Comment: do you know how ?

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041740/how-to-set-global-api-baseurl-used-in-usefetch-in-nuxt-3

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not sure but you may try that one.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  axios.create({
    baseURL: config.public.apiUrl,
  })
}
```

`useRuntimeConfig()` needs to be called inside of the function.

Comment: no it does not work

Answer (score -1):

**your .env file should like this**

```
BASE_URL= "http://www.a.com/"
```

and your nuxt.config like this

```
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    }
},
```

then add this to your service file

```
import axios from 'axios'

const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().BASE_URL,
})
export default http
```