# Async function doesn't run upon page load

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using `Nuxt v3.8.0` (which came with `Vue v3.3.7`). After implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73636631/871404), I have the following:

```
// .env
BASE_URL = https://www.my-website.com/wp/wp-json

// composables/customFetch.js
export const customFetch = (request, opts) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  return useFetch(request, { baseURL: config.public.baseURL, ...opts })
}

// index.vue
<script setup>
import { customFetch } from '@/composables/customFetch'
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
</script>
```

After page load, `customFetch()` never runs. But if I modify anything in the page's code such that `Nuxt` automatically updates the page, then `customFetch()` does load now.

What's going on? Why is it not working by itself upon page load?

Comment: how are you determining whether it runs or not?  are you checking the returned variables in your UI, or actually checking the network tab of your browsers dev tools, or something else?

Comment: Network tab in devtools. Upon page load, there's no API call at all. If I change some unrelated detail within the code and save so that Nuxt/Vue updates the page, then the API call pops up in Network tab.

Comment: Having an `await` in setup makes the component an [async dependency, which requires special handling](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html). If you turn the `await` into a `.then()` or move it in an `onMounted`, does the error go away?

Answer (score 2):

The `<script setup>` block runs asynchronously, which means that data fetching code might not have been completed by the time the initial rendering is done. This can result in the data not being available immediately on page load.

To ensure that the data is available on page load, you can use the `onMounted` lifecycle hook. This ensures that the data fetching is completed before rendering the component:

```
<script setup>
import { customFetch } from '@/composables/customFetch'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

const fetchData = async () => {
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
  // Assign data to your reactive variables
}

onMounted(() => {
  fetchData()
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that, same result: API call isn't made upon page load - only after changing the code + Nuxt/Vue updating the page accordingly does the API call suddenly appear in Devtools Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Moritz Ringler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4883195/moritz-ringler)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77406121/async-function-doesnt-run-upon-page-load#comment136488452_77406121), Vue.js [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html) (an experimental feature): When `await` is used in the `setup` function, the component becomes an *asynchronous* component, which requires wrapping with a `<Suspense>` element to handle the loading state during the async operation.

> `<Suspense>` is a built-in component for orchestrating async dependencies in a component tree. It can render a loading state while waiting for multiple nested async dependencies down the component tree to be resolved.

Your code would then be:

```js
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <!-- Your component template here -->
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>

<script setup>
import { customFetch } from '@/composables/customFetch'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const data = ref(null)
const error = ref(null)

const fetchData = () => {
  customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(response => {
      data.value = response.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      error.value = err
    })
}

fetchData()
</script>
```

The component is wrapped with a `<Suspense>` element, which provides a loading fallback while the async operation is in progress.
The `await` expression is replaced with a `.then()` chain, which does not make the component async.
The `fetchData` function is called directly, without being wrapped in an `onMounted` hook, since the `await` expression has been replaced.

---

The error is:

```bash
[Vue warn]: Hydration node mismatch:
- Client vnode: Symbol(v txt)
(start of fragment) at <Index anVnodeunmounted-fnconVnodelinmounted> ref-Ref< undefined > >
at <RouteProvider key="/Vnode=
Server rendered DOM:
{isode: true, skip: true, type: (-), props: (-), key: null, -) route-
(fullPath: '/', hash: query: (-), name: "index", path: /-)
at <Routerview name-undefined route-undefined >
at <HuxtPage>
at <Default ref-Ref< undefined >>
at cLayoutLoader key-"default" layoutProps (ref: RefImpl} name="default" >
at <MuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps (ref: Refimpl} key="default" name="default"
at (NuxtLayout>
at <Body class="antialiased duration-300 transition-colors text-gray-808 dark:text-gray-200 bg-white dark:bg-gray-950">
at <App key-3)
at NuxtRoot>
► [Vue warn]: Hydration children mismatch in <div>: server rendered element chunk-2322WV.js:1436 contains more child nodes than client vdom.
at <Index onVnodelinmounted-inconVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined >>>
at <RouteProvider key="/" nodes
(isNode: true, ship: true, type: (-), props: (-), bey: null, -) route-
▸ {fullPath: "/", hash: query: (-), name: 'index', path: '/', -} ...
at <RouterView name-undefined route=undefined >
at <MuxtPage>
at Default ref-Refs undefined > >
at <LayoutLoader key="default" layoutProps (ref: RefImpi) name="default" at <HuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps: (ref: RefImpl} key="default" name="default"
at NuxtLayout> at <Body class="antialiased duration-300 transition-colors text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 bg-white dark:bg-gray-950
at App key-3 >
at <Nuxtiloot)
```

The hydration mismatch errors typically occur when the server-rendered markup differs from the client-side rendered markup. That can happen when data is fetched on the client side after the server has already rendered the page.

Since Nuxt.js supports [Server-Side Rendering (SSR)](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/introduction#server-side-rendering), you need to make sure the data fetching happens on the server-side as well, so that the initial render matches between server and client.

To address this issue in Nuxt 3, you can use the new [`useAsyncData`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data) or [`useFetch`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) composable inside the `setup` function, which is designed to work with Nuxt's SSR features.
These functions will automatically fetch data on the server when generating the page and then reuse this data on the client side to avoid hydration issues.

`index.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
import { useAsyncData } from 'nuxt/app'
import { customFetch } from '@/composables/customFetch'

const { data: projects, pending, error } = useAsyncData('projects', () =>
  customFetch('/projects/v1/posts').then(response => response.data)
)
</script>

<template>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <template v-for="project in projects">
        {{ project }}
      </template>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

By using `useAsyncData`, Nuxt will handle the data fetching *both* on the server and client.
The `'projects'` key is used for caching the data so that it does not refetch on the client if it was already fetched on the server.
Now, when the page is rendered on the server, it will already include the fetched data, which should prevent a hydration mismatch.

Make sure your Nuxt version supports `useAsyncData`. If not, you may need to update your Nuxt version or use alternative methods provided by the version you are using.

See more at [Nuxt 3 Data Fetching](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching).

---

> I am still getting "Hydration node mismatch" console errors, though (mismatch between "Client vnode" and "Server rendered DOM").

The hydration error messages usually give you details about where the mismatch is occurring. Look closely at the logs and compare the server-rendered output with what the client is trying to render.

Verify that you are using the `useAsyncData` or `useFetch` properly. These functions should automatically handle data fetching on both the server and client side. Make sure there is no client-side code that could run before the server-side fetch completes, as this could cause discrepancies.

And inspect the data being fetched by `useAsyncData`. If the data is not serializable (e.g., contains functions or circular references), it could cause hydration issues.

Make sure all dynamic data used in the initial render is fetched during server-side rendering. Any differences in data between the server and client will cause hydration errors. And make also sure that there is no non-deterministic content (like dates, random numbers, etc.) being rendered without being wrapped in `client-only` components or fetched client-side after mount.

If you are using static site generation, make sure the data fetching strategy aligns with SSG. Static sites should not have server-side data dependencies unless you are using Incremental Static Regeneration.

Sometimes, plugins or modules can cause hydration issues. Review any custom configurations or third-party modules you have added to your Nuxt project.

Just to be sure, your HTML must be valid and there must not be any missing tags or syntax errors that could be causing the client-rendered HTML to differ from the server-rendered HTML.

For any components or parts of your application that are meant to run only in the browser (like those interacting with `window` or `document`), use the `<ClientOnly>` component in Nuxt to prevent them from being rendered on the server.

As a last resort, try to **simplify** your component to the most basic version that reproduces the error. That can sometimes help isolate the specific cause of the problem.

---

> The hydration issue occurs with a brand new Nuxt3 project (no plugin/module installed, no extra config added, nothing), simply by running the code mentioned above.

Since the problem remains with the stripped-down version, it might not be related to your application's specific logic or configuration, but rather how Nuxt 3 handles server-side rendering and hydration in combination with the experimental `<Suspense>` feature.

Make sure you are running the latest version of Nuxt 3, as it is still under active development and many issues are resolved in newer releases.
As a test, try removing the `<Suspense>` component and see if the hydration error persists. That can help isolate whether `<Suspense>` is the cause:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="project in projects">
      {{ project.ID }}
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Also, simplify the template further by removing the `v-for` directive and rendering static content to check if the issue is related to dynamic rendering.

Manually compare the server-rendered HTML with the client-side HTML. Look for differences in the DOM structure, attributes, or content.

Temporarily replace the async data with static data to confirm that the issue is related to data fetching:

```html
<script setup>
const projects = [{ ID: 'static1' }, { ID: 'static2' }];
</script>
```

Verify that your `.env` file is correctly configured and that `BASE_URL` is being picked up by Nuxt. A discrepancy here could cause server/client mismatches.

Add `console.log` statements before the `return` in `useAsyncData` to log the data being fetched and make sure it matches between server and client.

So something like:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Removed the Suspense component for testing -->
    <template v-for="project in projects" :key="project.ID">
      {{ project.ID }}
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { customFetch } from '@/customFetch'

// Use ref to create a reactive reference for projects
const projects = ref([])

// Fetch data on mounted to ensure it's done client-side
onMounted(async () => {
  console.log('Client-side fetch on mounted')
  try {
    const response = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
    console.log('Data fetched on client:', response.data)
    projects.value = response.data
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching data on client:', err)
  }
})
</script>
```

---

> ```
> Client-side fetch on mounted
> index.vue:18
> Data fetched on client:
> ▾ RefImpl (__v_isShallow: false, dep: undefined, _v_isRef: true, rawValue: null, value: null)
> dep: undefined
>
> >[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function chunk-U33Z7LWV.js:1436
> at <Index onVnodeUnmounted-in conVnodeUnmounted> ref-Ref< Proxy (Object) _v_ship: true} >> at <RouteProvider key="/" vnode=
>
> ► [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is chunk-UJ3Z7LWV.js:1436 likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/trepo-vuejs/core
> at <Index onVnodeUnmounted-inconVnodeUnmounted> ref-Ref< Proxy (Object) {_skip: true} >>
>
> ‣ Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ID') Index vue:3
> ```

The error message suggests that there is an attempt to read the property 'ID' from an undefined object within your `v-for` loop.
That would indicate that the data expected from `customFetch` is not structured as anticipated, or the fetch request is not resolving correctly before the render function tries to access the data.

The `Data fetched on client:` log shows that the `response.data` is `null`. That means that either the fetch request did not return any data or the data is not being assigned correctly to `projects.value`.
The `Unhandled error during execution of render function` and `Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush` are likely a result of trying to render with incomplete data.
The `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ID')` directly points to the fact that the `projects` array is still `null` when the template tries to access `project.ID`.

To address those errors, consider:

- checking the API response: Verify that the API endpoint used in `customFetch` is returning the expected data. You can do this by logging the response immediately after the fetch call, or by using a tool like Postman to directly test the API endpoint.
- handling the asynchronous data correctly: Make sure you are waiting for the data to be fetched before trying to render it. That might involve checking the state of `pending` if it is available from `useAsyncData` and rendering conditionally based on whether the data has loaded.
- adding an error handling: Since `customFetch` could throw an error, make sure you are catching and handling any potential errors that might occur during the fetch.

Result:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Add a check for projects to make sure it is not null -->
    <template v-if="projects" v-for="project in projects" :key="project.ID">
      {{ project.ID }}
    </template>
    <!-- You can also add a message for when there is no data yet -->
    <div v-if="!projects.length && !error">Loading...</div>
    <div v-if="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { customFetch } from '@/customFetch'

const projects = ref([])
const error = ref(null)

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
    if (response && response.data) {
      console.log('Data fetched on client:', response.data)
      projects.value = response.data
    } else {
      throw new Error('No data returned from the fetch')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching data on client:', err)
    error.value = err
  }
})
</script>
```

That code will wait for the data to be available before attempting to render it, and will also provide feedback if an error occurs or if the data is not yet available.

Comment: Thanks! My `index.vue` now looks like this: https://pastecode.dev/s/OP92nzow (virtually the same as the code you provided). But now I'm getting multiple hydration mismatch console errors: https://i.imgur.com/BpC44Il.png. I can't believe I'm having so much trouble trying to accomplish something so basic as fetch on page load. Nuxt3 documentation is also pretty useless because the examples it provides are way too scarce and too simple/incomplete (not matching real case scenarios). Thinking of giving up Nuxt3 tbh.

Comment: @drake035 OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks, still getting "Hydration node mismatch" console errors though (mismatch between "Client vnode" and "Server rendered DOM").

Comment: @drake035 OK, here are some more checks for you to consider. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I created a brand new Nuxt3 project. The only thing I did, from there, was to (1) copy `customFetch.js` (same content as in OP) into the root folder, (2) add `.env` file specifying `BASE_URL` and (3) replaced content of `app.vue` with this: https://pastecode.dev/s/IuhdXDIV. And yet, I still have these hydration errors: https://i.imgur.com/fgTuwMR.png. This is hopeless lol.

Comment: Just to clarify: the hydration issue occurs with a *brand new Nuxt3 project* (no plugin/module installed, no extra config added, nothing), simply by running the code I showed in my previous reply a few minutes ago.

Comment: @drake035 OK, I have edited the answer to add some more test, based on your simplified project.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I now have these console errors: https://i.imgur.com/e1gLWeM.png. And strangely in Network tab, no API call shows up.

Comment: @drake035 OK. I have edited the answer to include your error message, and some possible remediations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the `await` call during setup, which turns the component into an async dependency.

There are two ways to deal with it:

1. Rewrite the component
2. Wrap it with Suspense

---

The first approach means that you initialize your refs with empty values and use `.then()` instead of `await` to fill them:

```html
<script setup>
import { customFetch } from '@/composables/customFetch'
const data = ref([])
customFetch('/projects/v1/posts').then((response) => data.value = response.data)
</script>
```

Of course, you can throw all sorts of js at it to solve it differently, as long as you avoid the top-level `await` and declare your refs during setup phase:

```html
<script setup>
import { customFetch } from '@/composables/customFetch'
const data = ref([]) // <---- define ref during setup
;(async() => { // <---- wrap async call in iife
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
  data.value = data
})()
</script>
```

Here is a simple [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UrFOwzAU/JUnL6RSSAtlgrQSIAYYAEG3uoOVvBQXx45sJy2K8u88p03pgLrFd+fT3cUtu6+qpKmR3bLUZVZWHhz6uppzLcvKWA8tWCygg8KaEi5IesE115nRzoMyIpd6DbOgibytcTRQufDigC9XhHJ9Fwn3o7NoBLM5tFwDiK2QHjRu4Z3MpcPIojOqwaCgGAtZoqn9gMZwM5lMRmQGvX3SCFWTFpZX8XU8XQX8kOhIFUI55LobRXQtHe8rUjk6eCwrJTzSCSDNZQPNpSxmnB08OJsPbkmSjklwqkTynbdtyNF1A5uOj6YsZt7RFIVcJxtnNA3cd+YsM2UlFdq3ykuairPb/RqBE0qZ7UuPhTXjAc++MPv+B9+4XcA4e6eN0DbI2ZHzwq7R7+mnz1fc0feRLE1eK1KfIT/C6nXIuJc91Dqn2Ce6Pu1z/0xopYV72nnUbigVggZl1+s5o6fzeKb6X9xpMu3v0W9j3S/ad+A3)

---

The second option uses [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html), which can handle async dependencies directly. For this, you can leave your component as it is, but you have to wrap it in a suspense **in the parent component.**

So let's assume your component is `<Index/>`, than you can use it in a parent like this:

```html
// IndexParent.vue
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <Index/>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

or, if you want to show a loading indicator:

```html
// IndexParent.vue
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <Index/>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      loading...
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

Note that Suspense is still an experimental feature.

Here is a snippet (easier to restart):

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const AsyncDependency = {
  template: `data: {{data}}`,
  async setup(){
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
    const data = ref([1,2,3])
    return {data}
  }
}

const App = { 
  components: {AsyncDependency},
  template: `
    <Suspense>
      <template #default>
        <AsyncDependency/>
      </template>
      <template #fallback>
       loading...
      </template>
    </Suspense>
  `,
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

---

Note that in

```
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
```

the resulting variables will not be reactive, which is usually not what you want in Vue. Instead, you probably want to put the data into refs:

```
const response = await customFetch('/projects/v1/posts')
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = toRefs(response)
```