# Nuxt: How to share an api base url among use cases of useFetch?

Tags: nuxt3

This is my first time creating a node application. It's a challenge to me but thanks to the help received on this site, I manage, as best I can, to find my way.

My present question is by what underlying mechanism of NUXT I can properly change the base url of my API

What I know so far is that I can share variables between frontend and backend once declared as follows in nuxt.config.ts.

```
import svgLoader from "vite-svg-loader";
const isProdEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const develAPI_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
const prodAPI_URL = 'https://subdomaim.api.domaim.fr:8000/api/'
const API_URL = isProdEnv ? prodAPI_URL: develAPI_URL

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ["@/assets/scss/global.scss"],
  modules: [
    // ...
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    "@nuxt/ui",
    "@samk-dev/nuxt-vcalendar",
  ],
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
     additionalData: '@use "@/assets/scss/_vars.scss" as *;',
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [svgLoader()],
  },
  typescript: {
    typeCheck: false,
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase: API_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

What I thought a priori was that apiBase was a reserved name in Nuxt and that it would be taken into account automatically when using useFetch like in the following example.

```
async function onSubmit(event: FormSubmitEvent<any>) {
    const { data, pending, error } = await useFetch('/api/person', {
        method: props.mode === "create" ? "POST" : "PUT",
        body: event.data,
     });
     ....
```

In fact this is not the case.
So I came to reconstruct the url in this way

```
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
const { public: { apiBase }} = useRuntimeConfig()

async function onSubmit(event: FormSubmitEvent<any>) {
    let create_url=new URL('/api/person',API_URL).href
    const { data, pending, error } = await useFetch(create_url, {
        method: props.mode === "create" ? "POST" : "PUT",
        body: event.data,
    });
```

Is this the way to use a base url in Nuxt or is there a way to implicitely take the apiBase variable into account without having to recreate the url at each use of useFetch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set global API baseUrl used in useFetch in Nuxt 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041740/how-to-set-global-api-baseurl-used-in-usefetch-in-nuxt-3)